# Dynamic number of inputs for a function in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between using `*args` and getting a list as input for having a dynamic number of inputs for a function.

Do these two ways have any advantages in comparison with the other?

Comment: One has N arguments, the other 1 argument that is a list of N items.

Comment: Do you mean `*args` ?

Comment: @Rahul yes your right. I corrected it

Answer (score 4):

It's just a difference in what type of arguments the function expects. They are fairly interchangeable; which you choose is mostly a matter of preference (though see the exceptions at the end of the answer).

Given the following definitions:

```
# Separate arguments
def foo(*args):
    pass

# Single sequence of arguments
def bar(list_of_args):
    pass

x = [1, 2, 3]
```

These two calls are equivalent:

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
foo(*x)      # Unpack a list before calling
```

And these two calls are equivalent:

```
bar(x)
bar([1, 2, 3])  # Explicitly pack individual arguments
```

---

You mentioned `**args` in your question. The name of the parameter isn't really important; the special behavior is indicated by a parameter name beginning with one or two `*`s. One `*` indicates arbitrary positional arguments, as shown above. Two `*`s indicates arbitrary keyword arguments. Conventionally, the two most common names are `*args` and `**kwargs`.

A brief example similar to the above:

```
# Arbitrary keyword arguments
def foo(**kwargs):
    pass

# Single dict d
def bar(d):
    pass

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

# Equivalent
foo(*d)
foo(a=1, b=2)

# Equivalent
bar(d)
bar(dict(a=1, b=2))
```

---

Exception: if the function actually expects to *mutate* a value, you can't replace that effectively with a `*`/`**` parameter. Example:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    kwargs['foo'] = 3
```

This adds a mapping of `'foo'` to 3 to the dictionary, but it is a *temporary* dictionary created just for the call to `foo`. Nothing outside the function has a reference to that dictionary, so the update doesn't have any effect after `foo` returns.

Similar logic applies to `*args`, but since `args` is a tuple, and tuples are immutable, there's little you could do with the argument anyway. That said, if the function really expects a list, and not just an arbitrary sequence of arguments, you have to define your function to handle that.

```
def foo(some_list):    # can't use *args here
    some_list.append(3)
```

You can't effectively define that as

```
def foo(*args):
    args.append(3)
```

because `foo` receives a temporary tuple, not a list object that

Comment: Do these two ways have any advantages in comparison with the other? (Please check the update of the question)

Comment: No, it's pretty much a matter of preference. Usually, you choose the one that matches the expected use of a function.

Comment: Please update your answer with your current claim in comment.